# Login Authentication failing for Asp.net MVC and Wordpress sites on windows server 2019 with Plesk Obsidian

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress, plesk

My server was breached recently where a person injected malicious javascript to all javascript files in all folders and  in all websites on this dedicated server.

I moved to a new windows server 2019 with plesk Obsidian.  Wordpress websites created on this new  dedicated server using the WordPress toolkit prevents admin login.  I have reset passwords but cant log in.  I have migrated an old wordpress website to this new server and same problem I cant login to admin.

I also have my custom asp.net mvc applications and I am not able to login or register. For my asp.net mvc applications when I try to login I get

```
System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: 
The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
```

Though when you inspect code source you can see the hidden cookies. This was a live site that people have their accounts on it was working alright on my old windows 2016 webserver.  I have just 2 days ago deployed a  similar asp.net websites on an aws lightsail provision and is working perfectly well.

When I contact the server providers they tell me it is my websites and it has nothing to do with the server.    Do I have no other option but to believe that this has nothing to do with the server setup or IIS configuration but WordPress and my asp.net mvc websites.   I have been in this suspended state over a week now.  I am just wondering if this has ever happened to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out Web Application Firewall settings in Plesk was the culprit.  I  selected OWASP(free) and Fast configuration. After everything is working.